# Shell context menu without NEW option

Tags: windows, vb.net, shell, contextmenu

I´m developing an application to manage folders and files, and I'm showing the context menu for folders but it doesn't show the "NEW" option.

When I show the context menu for a folder the option "NEW" doesn't show.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
iShellFolder.GetUIObjectOf(IntPtr.Zero,
                           System.Convert.ToUInt32(apidl.Length),
                           apidl,
                           (riid),
                           (rgfReserved),
                           obj2)


If (Me.ContextMenu2 IsNot Nothing) Then
    ' Si ya hay un ContextMenu2 lo elimina
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Me.ContextMenu2)
    Me.ContextMenu2 = Nothing
End If
' Crea el ContextMenu2
Me.ContextMenu2 = TryCast(obj2, Win32.IContextMenu2)

If (Me.ContextMenu2 IsNot Nothing) Then
    ' Si lo creó
    Dim mousePosition As Point = Control.MousePosition
    Dim uFlags As UInt32 = FirstCMFFlag
    If uFlags <> CMF.CMF_NOVERBS Then
        If pidlList.Count = 1 Then
            uFlags = uFlags Or CMF.CMF_CANRENAME Or CMF.CMF_EXPLORE
        End If
        If (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Shift) = Keys.Shift Then
            uFlags = uFlags Or CMF.CMF_EXTENDEDVERBS    ' 256
        End If
    End If

    ' Presenta y lee la opción del ContextMenu
    Me.ContextMenu2.QueryContextMenu(menu.Handle, 0, 1, &H7FFF, uFlags)
    Dim menuResult As UInt32 = 0
    If FirstMenuResult = 0 Then   ' No trae ningún valor a ejecutar
        Dim flg As UInt32 = &H100   '  returncmd (&h100)
        menuResult = Win32.TrackPopupMenu(menu.Handle, flg,
                                                    mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y,
                                                    0, parent, IntPtr.Zero)
    Else
        menuResult = FirstMenuResult
    End If
```

Comment: When you post a question here, it's your responsibility to do all you can to help us help you. It's good that you posted formatted code but leaving a wad of leading whitespace is not acceptable. It just makes it harder for us to read the code, having to continually scroll horizontally. If it's too much trouble to remove it after pasting, don't copy it in the first place. VS let's you copy an arbitrary block of text by holding down the Alt key.

Comment: For the record, I was originally on a phone, which required a lot of scrolling. There's less scrolling required on a PC but there would be none without that unnecessary whitespace. Always do all you can to make it easier for us to help. You never need all that leading whitespace so never include it.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're adding the New option in your sample code. When do you do it?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how can I add the new option?